# Why $a,b$ assumed coprime?

Tags: group-theory, maximal-subgroup

I have a question about an exercise in Dummit-Foote Abstract algebra:

This is the exercise-solution I am referring to:

[image]

> My question is about problem 3's solution of $\implies$ direction. I am trying to figure out why do we assume in that proof that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. I don't see that this assumption is used anywhere in the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that assumption has to be dropped, otherwise the proof will only give that $k$ is a *prime power*.

In what is possibly a critical passage, $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$ implies $\gcd(ab,n)=1$ without any need to assume $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. This is just, for instance, because if $p$ is a prime dividing both $a b$ and $n$, then $p$ divides either $a$ (and thus $\gcd(a,n)$) or $b$ (and thus $\gcd(b,n)$).

Comment: Wow! I did not see that in that case we would only know that $k$ is prime power!!! Thank you so much for that. Thanks for going through this big post.

Comment: And yes, many congrats for crossing 55k :) (just saw your profile page.)